Universal logicians
Henri Poincaré is often considered to be the last universal mathematician, meaning the last individual who made contributions across all areas of mathematics of his time. Today, even a prodigious mathematician like Terence Tao is not deeply involved in every area, such as algebraic geometry. The general consensus is that it is unlikely anyone will achieve this level of universal contribution again.
However, in the field of mathematical logic, which is relatively recent and has a smaller community, there may still be universalists.
My question is:
Who would be considered a universal logician nowadays, having made significant contributions to proof/type theory, model theory, set theory, and computability theory?
Or if no such person currently exists, who was the last individual to qualify as a universal logician?

Probably Kurt Gödel.

@MauroALLEGRANZA He is indeed a good candidate

This is a comment but too long for the comment format.
I personally consider the notion of a "universal mathematician" a pop-folklore notion. It has definitional problems and problems of good delineation. It is indeed pop-folklore that Poincare was the "last universal mathematician" but this leaves completely open what the term means and if under suitable definition it is justified or justifiable.
Furthermore, it is also question if it indeed fits observations over time, i.e. under suitable definition of "universal" is it indeed sensible to say that he was the last.
First off the notion of "universal". What does it mean? Do we mean "someone who knows everything and makes some contribution to it?" Or do we mean a pop notion of "someone who is very broad in their interests and contributions?" The fact that this is in pop discourse on the notion something that is rarely if ever encountered is a problem for being clear about this notion.
For example an answer on quora by Rajratna Adsul on the question too struggles to give one definition of the universal mathematician and instead offers two:

A universal mathematician is someone who contributes to a vast number
of fields of mathematics in quite distinct areas or someone who has
changed the entire face of mathematics as it stands.

I hope it's easy to see that these are in fact different definitions and lead to different ways to probing if what we consider is sensible.
Now for the question of "last", let me first talk about contemporaries. In the above mentioned quora post, Poincare and Hilbert are mentioned. I personally would consider Klein an interesting figure to add to the discussion. After all he wrote an expansive review of the mathematical developments in the 19th century, so certainly an argument can be made that he was widely knowledgeable and widely interested, and died after Poincare. Hilbert of course also died after Poincare. So how did we even decide on "last"?
Let me look forward. Mathematics education even today retains a notion of holistic education. Graduate qualifying exams do not just test a graduate level of mastery in a narrow field, but in numerous core fields of mathematics. While it is of course impossible to teach all of mathematics (or all of any modern field of inquiry), there is certainly a kind of "universalist" notion underlying the educational structure.
That said let's take some examples:
V. I. Arnold: Interested in relation of mathematics and physics, drew widely on many different fields of mathematics, such as diophantine equations, algebraic and differential topology, differential geometry, algebra. Was he a universalist?
M. Gromov: Deemed to be a geometer, but with wide ranging and eclectic contributions. Stamping out new topics or structures not considered before him (perhaps in analogy to Poincare and algebraic topology?), publications and intererest in biology and genetics? Is he a universalist? If no what is the demarcation to Poincare?
Saunders Mac Lane: Contributions to algebraic topology, but unifier of mathematical structure theory in the work of category theory, exemplifies the use of category theory in broad areas of mathematics, unifying considerations of geometry, topology, and logic. Was he a universalist?
Jean Dieudonne and the Bourbaki program: Jean Dieudonne wrote on what can be seen as comprehensive vistas of pure mathematics. Does that make him a universalist?
Langlands program: A vast unification effort of many branches of mathematics, are mathematicians who work in the area required to be universalist to understand broader conceptions of the program?
Edward Witten: Not considered a mathematician but drawing of broad topics of mathematics to formulate theoretical physics theories with such mastery to get distinguished recognitions by the mathematics community. Does that make him a universalist?
And to loop back to Poincare, if we look carefully, no doubt we find areas of mathematics and physics to which he hasn't contributed. If we use levels of non-engagement as counterexamples with others, how does that impact how we look at Poincare?
I believe more examples can be brought to question the notions under consideration here. I personally find the notion of the "last universal mathematician" to have a sentimental component to delineate 19th century enlightenment polymaths from 20th century specializations, and perhaps there is something loosely to it. However, I think, at least with respect to be clear about the history of science we need to be careful to take popular notions attributed to historical figures as good models to interpret the history of science through these scientists.

Thank you for your detailed comment. I agree that the definition is vague and needs to be treated with subtlety, but the fact that the same names come up so often suggests that it's not empty. I also think that in the specific case of logic, because it is more recent, it is easier to give a definition of "universal".

@B.Peterson I would suggest that certain folklore notions come up often is a function that they are repeated often. I.e. I think we have to be careful to suggest that a notion is "not empty" because it's repeated by many. The logical fallacies involved here is for example the "argument ad populum". In other words we need to probe if a notion is sensibly, not assume it is by popularity.

This is not what I am saying, the logical fallacy involved here is straw man ☺ Jokes aside, my point is that if a term is used by a linguistic community, then it has a meaning, possibly a vague one. Then, the fact that the same names come again and again (nobody would cite Wiles or Perelman for example, despite their popularity) indicate that this is not that vague

I think there is a broader topic here. It is the general acceptance of vague folklore "histories" in mathematics vis-a-vis serious historiography of mathematics. I find it particularly interesting because internally mathematics views itself as being concerned with precision, i.e. a notion being "not that vague" is not a particularly compelling reason to accept something. I'll open a question that will allows us to engage in this broader issue by making it source and facts based, and perhaps clarify what I am getting at.
